# Using Laravel Debugbar, how can I disable exception logging?

Tags: php, laravel, phpdebugbar

I'm using the [Laravel Debugbar Package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/tree/1.8) to display debug information. I'm noticing that the debug bar is logging errors to the log whenever an exception occurs. I would rather this doesn't happen, since I am running my own custom exception handler which collects information in the format I prefer and I have it logging to the log file as well.

So for example when I mistype a route name, I get the message saved twice to the log file:

> [2015-02-11 16:21:02] local.ERROR: Method [fdfdgfd] does not exist.
>
> [2015-02-11 16:21:04] local.ERROR: Debugbar exception: Method
>   UserController::fdfdgfd() does not exist [] []

How can I disable exception logging with the Debugbar?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but in case anyone still needs an answer. Set

```php
'storage' => [ 'enabled' => false, ]
```

In `laravel-debugbar/config/debugbar.php`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent or disable exception logging for `Debugbar` package.

> 1. For completely turn off log.
>    open edit `.env` file and add `DEBUGBAR_ENABLED` variable as **false** value

```
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false
```

> 2. Just want to disable log files in storage directory.

Publish `Debugbar` configuration file by following command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider
```

you will get success message like.

```
Copied File [\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-debugbar\config\debugbar.php] To [\config\debugbar.php]
Publishing complete.
```

Open `\config\debugbar.php` file

```
'storage' => [
    'enabled'    => false, /// here change it to false
    'path'       => storage_path('debugbar'), 
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this package, but it seems like it provides decent configuration.

Try to set this value to `false`: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/blob/1.8/src/config/config.php#L90

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately, that only removes the Exceptions tab in the Debugbar, but it doesn't disabled the error logging.